# Declaring a list of arrays in Bash

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I was trying to declare a variable in Bash with a list of arrays, the question is, is it possible to traverse individual array's value in combination one by one in Bash script.
For e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

declare -a r_Arr=("east" "west" "north")
declare -a u_Arr=(12 233 131)
declare -a v_Arr=(33 54 34)
items="${r_Arr[*]} ${u_Arr[*]} ${v_Arr[*]}"
```

Now how do I get values like {east,12,33} and {west,233,54} from items

Comment: Do you need a list of _arrays_? Do you have to use arrays?

Comment: Arrays do not nest. They are not designed to be the building blocks of more complicated data structures, only to allow storing a collection of arbitrary strings (mainly as a set of arguments to supply to a command).

Comment: There is, in fact, no array *value* in `bash`, only array syntax to allow a single name to refer to a collection of related parameters.

Comment: Can you use zsh instead of bash?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop :

```
#!/bin/bash -x

declare -a r_Arr=("east" "west" "north")
declare -a u_Arr=(12 233 131)
declare -a v_Arr=(33 54 34)
items="${r_Arr[*]} ${u_Arr[*]} ${v_Arr[*]}"

for ((i=0; i<${#r_Arr[@]}; i++)); do
    echo "${r_Arr[i]}" "${u_Arr[i]}" "${v_Arr[i]}"
done
```

Comment: May as well get rid of `items`, as it's not being used.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a while loop as follows:

```
counter=0
while [ $counter -lt ${#r_Arr[@]} ]
do
    echo {${r_Arr[$counter]}","${u_Arr[$counter]}","${v_Arr[$counter]}}
    ((counter++))
done
```

This would result in the following output:

```
{east,12,33}
{west,233,54}
{north,131,34}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Store data in a space separated newline separated text file. Use a while loop to read it. Use `grep` and standard unix tools `awk` to process it. Linux is used to line-based values.

```
filecontent=\
'east 12 33
west 322 131
north 54 34'
while IFS=' ' read -r direction num1 num2; do
       echo "$direction $num1 $num2"
done <<<"$filecontent"
```

Even, if starting from arrays, first paste them together anyway, and then use the while loop presented above:

```
paste -sd' ' <(
    printf "%s\n" "${r_arr[@]}"
  ) <(
    printf "%s\n" "${u_arr[@]}"
  ) <(
     printf "%s\n" "${v_arr[@]}"
  )
```