# How to iterate over multiple variables and echo them using Shell Script?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, unix, echo

Consider the below variables which are dynamic and might change each time. Sometimes there might even be 5 variables, But the length of all the variables will be the same every time.

```
var1='a b c d e... upto z'
var2='1 2 3 4 5... upto 26'
var3='I II III IV V... upto XXVI'
```

I am looking for a generalized approach to iterate the variables in a for loop & My desired output should be like below.

```
a,1,I
b,2,II
c,3,III
d,4,IV
e,5,V
.
.
goes on upto
z,26,XXVI
```

If I use nested loops, then I get all possible combinations which is not the expected outcome.

Also, I know how to make this work for 2 variables using for loop and shift using below link
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/390283/how-to-iterate-two-variables-in-a-sh-script

Comment: There's really no good way to do this in POSIX shell. In shells that support arrays, you can create 3 separate arrays and iterate over the *indices*. You should probably look into using a different language (with decent data structure support) if you need this kind of "zipping" behavior.

Comment: Are the fields separated by spaces? If yes you could assign these values to bash indexed arrays instead (`var1=( a b c d e...z )`) and use a loop over the indexes. Have a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69477714/declaring-a-list-of-arrays-in-bash) maybe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The ever changing variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68864230/the-ever-changing-variable)

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek: No, that was too complex when comparing with my requirement. The paste option did it for me. Thanks for your response!

Comment: @AdarshR Indeed, `paste` solves this nicely, but I think the “nameref” solution in Bash also has its qualities — in particular, it is much easier to scale to an arbitrary number of variables (and requires just one command-line token per variable). I’ve [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486466/8584929) showing what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `paste`

```sh
paste -d , <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$var1") <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$var2") <(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"$var3")
```

```
a,1,I
b,2,II
c,3,III
d,4,IV
e...z,5...26,V...XXVI
```

But clearly having to add other parameter substitutions for more `varN`'s is not scalable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was really simple & worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

You need to "zip" two variables at a time.

```
var1='a b c d e...z'
var2='1 2 3 4 5...26'
var3='I II III IV V...XXVI'

zip_var1_var2 () {
    set $var1
    for v2 in $var2; do
        echo "$1,$v2"
        shift
    done
}

zip_var12_var3 () {
    set $(zip_var1_var2)
    for v3 in $var3; do
        echo "$1,$v3"
        shift
    done
}

for x in $(zip_var12_var3); do
  echo "$x"
done
```

If you are willing to use `eval` and are sure it is safe to do so, you can write a single function like

```
zip () {
    if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
        eval echo \$$1
        return
    fi

    a1=$1
    shift
    x=$*

    set $(eval echo \$$a1)
    for v in $(zip $x); do
        printf '=== %s\n' "$1,$v" >&2
        echo "$1,$v"
        shift
    done
}

zip var1 var2 var3  # Note the arguments are the *names* of the variables to zip
```

If you can use arrays, then (for example, in `bash`)

```
var1=(a b c d e)
var2=(1 2 3 4 5)
var3=(I II III IV V)

for i in "${!var1[@]}"; do
    printf '%s,%s,%s\n' "${var1[i]}" "${var2[i]}" "${var3[i]}"
done
```

Comment: I tried out implementing the arrays option with no luck. I might be missing something or we may be using a POSIX shell. Anyway, Thanks a lot for your response. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -le '@in = map { [split] } @ARGV; for $i ( 0..$#{ $in[0] } ) { print join ",", map { $in[$_][$i] } 0..$#in; }' "$var1" "$var2" "$var3"
```

Prints:

```
a,1,I
b,2,II
c,3,III
d,4,IV
e,5,V
z,26,XXVI
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

The input variables must be quoted with double quotes "like so", to keep the blank-separated words from being treated as separate arguments.
`@ARGV` is an array of the command line arguments, here `$var1`, `$var2`, `$var3`.
`@in` is an array of 3 elements, each element being a reference to an array obtained as a result of splitting the corresponding element of `@ARGV` on whitespace. Note that `split` splits the string on whitespace by default, but you can specify a different delimiter, it accepts regexes.
The subsequent `for` loop prints `@in` elements separated by comma.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlvar`: Perl predefined variables](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following is (almost) a copy [of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68864790/8584929) with a few tweaks that make it fit this question.

## The Original Question

First let’s assign a few variables to play with, 26 tokens in each of them:

```sh
var1="$(echo {a..z})"
var2="$(echo {1..26})"
var3="$(echo I II III IV \
             V{,I,II,III} IX \
             X{,I,II,III} XIV \
             XV{,I,II,III} XIX \
             XX{,I,II,III} XXIV \
             XXV XXVI)"
var4="$(echo {A..Z})"
var5="$(echo {010101..262626..10101})"
```

Now we want a “magic” function that zips an arbitrary number of variables, ideally in pure Bash:

```sh
zip_vars var1       # a trivial test
zip_vars var{1..2}  # a slightly less trivial test
zip_vars var{1..3}  # the original question
zip_vars var{1..4}  # more vars, becasuse we can
zip_vars var{1..5}  # more vars, because why not
```

What could **`zip_vars`** look like? Here’s one in pure Bash, without any external commands:

```sh
zip_vars() {
  local var
  for var in "$@"; do
    local -a "array_${var}"
    local -n array_ref="array_${var}"
    array_ref=(${!var})
    local -ar "array_${var}"
  done
  local -n array_ref="array_${1}"
  local -ir size="${#array_ref[@]}"
  local -i i
  local output
  for ((i = 0; i < size; ++i)); do
    output=
    for var in "$@"; do
      local -n array_ref="array_${var}"
      output+=",${array_ref[i]}"
    done
    printf '%s\n' "${output:1}"
  done
}
```

How it works:

0. It splits all variables (passed by reference (by variable name)) into arrays. For each variable `varX` it creates a local array `array_varX`.

   - It would be actually *way easier* if the input variables were already Bash arrays to start with (see below), but … we stick with the original question initially.
1. It determines the `size` of the first array and then blindly expects all arrays to be of that `size`.
2. For each index `i` from `0` to `size - 1` it concatenates the `i`th elements of all arrays, separated by `,`.

## Arrays Make Things Easier

If you use Bash arrays from the very start, the script will be shorter and look simpler and there won’t be any string-to-array conversions.

```sh
zip_arrays() {
  local -n array_ref="$1"
  local -ir size="${#array_ref[@]}"
  local -i i
  local output
  for ((i = 0; i < size; ++i)); do
    output=
    for arr in "$@"; do
      local -n array_ref="$arr"
      output+=",${array_ref[i]}"
    done
    printf '%s\n' "${output:1}"
  done
}

arr1=({a..z})
arr2=({1..26})
arr3=(    I II III    IV
       V{,I,II,III}   IX
       X{,I,II,III}  XIV
      XV{,I,II,III}  XIX
      XX{,I,II,III} XXIV
                    XXV
                    XXVI)
arr4=({A..Z})
arr5=({010101..262626..10101})

zip_arrays arr1       # a trivial test
zip_arrays arr{1..2}  # a slightly less trivial test
zip_arrays arr{1..3}  # (almost) the original question
zip_arrays arr{1..4}  # more arrays, becasuse we can
zip_arrays arr{1..5}  # more arrays, because why not
```